# SQl exception in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, double, sqlexception

I'm getting an SQLexception while debugging in VS. 
The error is: 
The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 8 ("@Pris"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

```
      string query = "INSERT INTO Indkøbsliste (ListID, ListeNr, Stregkode, Navn, Antal, Pris) Values (@ListID, @ListeNr, @Stregkode, @Navn, @Antal, @Pris)" ;
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myCon); 
      com.Parameters.Add("@ListID",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value=id; 
      com.Parameters.Add("@ListeNr",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value=listnr; 
      com.Parameters.Add("@Stregkode",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=strege ; 
      com.Parameters.Add("@Navn",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=navn ; 
      com.Parameters.Add("@Antal",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value=il.Antal; 
      com.Parameters.Add("@Pris",System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Value=il.Pris; 

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com.Dispose();
        myCon.Close();
```

I'm getting it at the ExecuteNonQuery. I know what the exception is about, but i Dont know haów to fix it. In my database i'm using float on my "prices", and in VS im using double. I think that I have read something that says a double en VS are like a float in sql.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of `il.Pris`

Comment: @Daniel SO wrote `i'm using float on my "prices", and in VS im using double`

Comment: I wasn't sure what `Pris` was.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when source exceeds the target parameter range. Ensure precision and scale are in range of target data type. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/4392aad1-eed0-4d6a-b891-90685b2e8258/